# CSS active styling is not remaining

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to keep a clicked button active as long as it is still clicked. I have tried a lot of things but this doesnt seem to work. The colored effect doesnt last more than 1 second and it's not depending from the click.
Here is my code :

```js
// Add active class to the current button

var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <table class="secondTable">
    <tr>
      <th><button class="btn" style="margin-left: -6px;">button1</button></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><button class="btn" style="margin-left: -6px;">button2</button></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have tried every possible thing but im not able to figure out what the problem is. The styling should just involve color changing.
NB: my css looks like this `.active { background-color: #545454; }`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks as it has worked here, but in my code it doesnt. Thats furstrating.

Comment: Isn't anything different in your local environment or code? Do you use any framework or something?

Comment: this shoud work, without JS: `.btn:active { background-color: #545454; }`. Notice the **:** [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Please [don't link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com), link to official documentation instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: Cool, @ChrisG, but mozilla didn't write the book either, helped, yes.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Who cares, as long as Mozilla isn't talking about ["JSON objects"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)